# Find all ring homomorphisms from $\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z \rightarrow \Bbb Z/n \Bbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, ring-homomorphism

> Find all ring homomorphisms from $\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z \rightarrow \Bbb Z/n \Bbb Z$, where $m,n\in \Bbb N_{>0}$.

I know that there exists a group homorphism between $\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z \rightarrow \Bbb Z/n \Bbb Z$ if and only if $n|m$ .

How should i continue ?

Comment: In your definition of a ring homomorphism, do you have to map the identity element to the identity element?

Comment: Yes. Does this mean there is only one ?

Comment: Yes, if there is one at all. To see this, reflect on where $i=1+1+\cdots+1$ can be sent.

Comment: Could you give more hints  , I feel stuck?

Comment: so i will be sent to f(1) + f(1) ... which is $ \overline i$

Comment: @ggok but $f(1)$ is $1$. What is $1+1+\cdots+1$ in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: i think i modulo n ?

Comment: $\bar i$, or however you wish to write it, is correct, for the reason you give. So if there is a homomorphism, there can be only one.

Comment: What would be an example where  n|m and there is no homomorphism ?

Comment: There is no such example, because in those cases, $f:\Bbb Z_m\to \Bbb Z_n$ given by $f(1)=1$ is indeed a homomorphism, and it is the only one. In any other case, there is no homomorphism. This, of course, you need to _check_.

Answer (score 1):

Basically $\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{m}$ and $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$. Then you can find out ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_{m}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$. And number of ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_{m}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ is $2^{\omega(n)-\omega(n/\gcd(m,n))}$, where $\omega(n)$ is number of distinct prime divisor of $n$. For example if we want to find out ring homomorphisms from $\Bbb Z/20\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb Z/30\Bbb Z$, i.e. from $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{30}$, then we will proceed like this. Common divisors of $20$ and $30$ are $ 1,2,5$ and $10$, so elements of this order in $\mathbb{Z}_{30}$ are $0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27 $ which give us ten group homomorphism and only $0,6,15,21 $ are idempotent elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{30}$ out of the ten above mentioned elements which give us four ring homomorphism i.e $\phi(x)=ax$ where $a$ is $0,6,15,21$.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that ring homomorphisms map $1$ to $1$.

Suppose $f\colon\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a ring homomorphism. Then, if $\pi\colon\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ is the canonical projection, $f\circ\pi$ is the *unique* ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Since $\pi$ is surjective, this shows that at most one ring homomorphism $f$ exists.

A necessary condition for existence is that $n\mathbb{Z}=\ker(f\circ\pi)\supseteq m\mathbb{Z}$, hence that $n\mid m$.

It's easy to see that this condition is also sufficient.